# Meteor+React getMeteorData not updating with correct data

Tags: meteor, reactjs, minimongo

I'm on the latest Meteor and React. I'm using the mongo `$text` search feature on the server to filter a query. I'm finding that my local data isn't changing, even though the query is being rerun correctly on the server.

My component looks something like this:

```
TodoLists = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  getMeteorData() {
    Meteor.subscribe('todoLists', this.props.query);
    const todoLists = TodoLists.find().fetch();

    //print out 1
    console.log(todoLists);
    return {
      todoLists
    };

    // same as:
    // return {
    //   todoLists: TodoLists.find().fetch()
    // };
  },
  ....
});
```

On the server, I have:

```
Meteor.publish('todoLists', function(query) {
      //if no search query
      if (!query) {
        return TodoLists.find();
      }

      //searching...
      const todoLists = TodoLists.find({ 
        $text: {
          $search: query
        }
      });

      //print out 2
      console.log(todoLists.fetch());
      return todoLists;
    }
  });
```

Interestingly, I found that when `this.props.query` changes, the publish function on the server *does* run, and prints out the filtered results to the console as directed (print out 2). However, when I print out the results from the `TodoLists.find().fetch()` on the client (print out 1), I just get all of the results, as if no filtering were being done.

Is there some reason this code isn't working? Why would the results be as expected on the server, but not correct on the client?

Comment: Two things come to my mind here: do you have "autopublish" enabled? Or do you have another subscription for the same collection? Note that on client side all data from every active subscription is merged into the collection.

Comment: Turned out I had another subscription to the same collection! Didn't realize they would be merged together. I'll accept as answer :)